# Simple Node.js application running slowly when outputting one or two characters

Tags: node.js

I'm just getting my teeth into Node.js. Am creating a simple page that acts as a random number generator, which should just return `0` or `1` to the client.

This test code works nice and quickly, taking just a few milliseconds:

```
var http = require('http'); // server

http.createServer(function (req, res) {    

    /*
     * Send headers.
     */
//   res.writeHead(200, {
//      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
//      'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate',
//      'Pragma': 'no-cache',
//      'Expires': '0',
//      'Surrogate-Control': 'no-store'
//    });
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });

    /*
     * Write output.
     */
    var rand = Math.random(); // (This will be replaced with the 'crypto' module.)

    // COMMENTING OUT THIS LINE MAKES THE RESPONSE VERY SLOW!!
    res.write("Rand: " + rand + "... ");

    if (rand < 0.5) {
        res.write("0");
    }
    else {
        res.write("1");
    }


    /*
     * Close output.
     */
    res.end();

}).listen(8080);
```

But, when I comment out the `res.write("Rand: " + rand + "... ");` line, the response takes about 5 or 6 seconds.

I'm following an online tutorial, but am wondering if I missing something very simple?

I'm currently using v10.19.0 of Node.js, but have tried other versions, too, which are just as slow.

*PS - Please don't mark this down just because it's a simple question. I've searched for an answer, can't find one, so am now asking. Thank you.*

**- UPDATE -**

It turns out that the slowness is dependent on how many characters are output.

Outputting "1" or "11" is slow. But outputting "111" or "1111" is fast.

To try and find a solution, instead of `res.write("1")`, I've tried `res.end("1")` and `res.end("1", "utf8")` - but they are just as slow.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you describe running this exact code on node v12.13.1 on Windows 10.  If I comment out that line, it is still just as quick.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either, macos running node v12.14.1.

Comment: i can't reproduce this in mac os node v14.2.0